# How to remove elements in an array?

Tags: javascript

I am making a card game and I display the cards on the screen as buttons, The id of the buttons is the value and the suit of the card i.e. "10S". I am trying to go through each of the cards and check to see if there is a pair. can remove the cards from my hand array however I can't remove the buttons from the screen

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.hand.length; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < this.hand.length; j++) {
          if (i != j && this.getHand()[i].getValue() == this.getHand()[j].getValue()) {
            this.hand.splice(j, 1);
            this.hand.splice(i, 1);
            document.getElementById(j).remove();
            document.getElementById(i).remove();
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            this.pairCount++;
          }
        }
      }
```

when it runs it says that it can't remove element of null. How do I remove the elements?
Edit: I can remove the cards from my hands array, however I am trying to remove the buttons from the screen by using document.getElementById(j).remove();

Comment: `i` and `j` are numbers. Do you have elements whose `id` is, for example, `10`?

Comment: Also, you're resetting `j` and `i` to zero on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: I suspect key to answering this is what `getHand()` returns.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca except he is comparing those values and "10s" != "10d", so the values must not include the entire id (ie 10s or 10d) only the card value not suit.

Comment: @JDunken you're almost surely right. I'll remove that comment.